# LEFT JOIN with OR Condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can I represent the following `LEFT JOIN` in Entity Framework?

```
SELECT * FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON 
(a.UserId = b.Field1 AND b.Field2 = SOME_VARIABLE) 
OR (a.UserId = b.Field2 AND b.Field1 = SOME_VARIABLE)
```

For `AND`s I know I can use complex anonymous types and `EQUALS` but I can't figure out how to handle `OR`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from a in context.aTable
            select new {
               A = a,
               B = (from b in context.bTable
                     where (a.UserId == b.Field1 && b.Field2 == SOME_VARIABLE) ||
                           (a.UserId == b.Field2 && b.Field1 == SOME_VARIABLE)
                    select b
                   ).DefaultIfEmpty()
            }
```

You can ignore `DefaultIfEmpty` depending on your need.

Comment: there must be , after A = a and == in comparisons. however even so, I get "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" error for the query passed to DefaultIfEmpty

Comment: @paulsimmons Oops! Updated.